# Парсер ТП Steam получает цены в разных валютах

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4, steam

Пишу парсер цен с ТП Steam, и столкнулся с такой проблемой: когда я начинаю парсить страницу https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/M249%20%7C%20Deep%20Relief%20%28Well-Worn%29, то цены выводятся в разных валютах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код парсера выглядит так:

```
    def parse_price(self, url):

    # url += '' Здесь я пытался добавить в конец аргументы по типу /render?currency=1
    # но это не сработало

    response = self.get_page(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all(id='searchResultsRows')
    for i in items:
        for j in i.find_all_next('span', class_='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee'):
            print(j.text.strip())
```

Функция для получения страницы:

```
def get_page(self, url):
    try:
        response = self.session.get(url, proxies=self.p.get())
        time.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))
        return response.content
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        self.p.change_proxy()
        return self.get_page(url)
```

Запросы отправляются через публичные прокси, и если ничего не вышло, то прокси меняется на другой. Все цены на скрине - это результат одного запроса, так что цены разные не из-за прокси. Заранее благодарю

Comment: Если не изменяет память там в куках или заголовках можно валюту прописать

Comment: Передавал в метод get ` param={'currency': 1} `, не сработало

Comment: Там не в param надо передавать а в куках или заголовках.

Comment: Не выходит, проверил через Network какие куки я отправляю, если в запросе отправляю ничего не меняется

Comment: Поигрался в Firefox, если убрать куку `steamLoginSecure`, то цены идут в разнобой. Судя по всему необходимо быть залогиненным, а валюта подтягивается из настроек профиля, никак иначе её явно не указать, насколько я понял.